# cloning a remote branch results in cloning all remote branches...why?

Tags: git, github

For some reason I keep on cloning all the remote branches when I just want to clone a specific remote branch.

I've google and search in SO for this one but can't seem to find it. I'm trying to clone a remote branch, say:

```
git clone https://github.com/whatever --branch foo
```

Once finished, if I check for branches:

```
git branch -a
```

I can see a list of ALL remote branches...maybe I got something wrong...but how can I clone just a specific branch only? I don't want/need the others...any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`--single-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) option:

```
git clone https://github.com/whatever --branch foo --single-branch <folder>
```